# Is it easy to see that a cubic surface $V$ in $CP^3$ has no holomorphic 2-forms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

More specifically, what facts do you need to know to conclude $H^2(V) = H^{1,1}$? In general, are there hypersurfaces in $CP^n$ without holomorphic $k$-forms for some $k$?

Comment: All you need for a nonsingular hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is that $\deg V\le n$. For $0<k<\dim V$, there's never a $k$-form.

Comment: This is probably very trivial but I am not seeing it for some reason. How is the adjunction formula enforcing the conditions you wrote above?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing more than adjunction formula, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula), knowing that $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^n} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: In terms of canonical class, if $X$ is a smooth surface of (to stay in your example), degree 3 in $\mathbb{P}^3$, you have $$ K_X= (K_{\mathbb{P}^3}+[X])|_X,$$ and this gives to you $K_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X(-1)$. Then you use $$ H^2(X) \cong H^0(X, K_X) \oplus H^{1,1}(X) \oplus H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$$ with the first (and then the third) term being zero, since $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$ is negative.